# Drop quality on resize image

Tags: php

I resize and upload Image from URL With this function. The problem is that after resizing and save Image the quality drop, Does anyone know which part causes the quality loss?

```
function resize($url, $width, $height, $savePath) {
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $src = ImageCreateFromString($data);
    $sw = ImageSX($src);
    $sh = ImageSY($src);
    $ratio = $sw / $sh;
    if ($sw > $sh) {
        $height = $width / $ratio;
    } else {
        $width = $height * $ratio;
    }
    $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
    ImageCopyResampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $sw, $sh);
    ImageJPEG($dst, $savePath, 100);
    ImageDestroy($dst);
    ImageDestroy($src);
}
```

usage:

```
$url = $image1;
$width = '480';
$height = '420';
$savePath = '../../images/'.$title2.'.jpg';
resize($url, $width, $height, $savePath);
```

also after resizing I add watermark on iamge, watermark code :

```
function watermark_image($target, $wtrmrk_file, $newcopy) {
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($wtrmrk_file);
    imagealphablending($watermark, false);
    imagesavealpha($watermark, true);
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    $img_w = imagesx($img);
    $img_h = imagesy($img);
    $wtrmrk_w = imagesx($watermark);
    $wtrmrk_h = imagesy($watermark);
    $dst_x = ($img_w / 2) - ($wtrmrk_w / 2); // For centering the watermark on any image
    $dst_y = ($img_h / 2) - ($wtrmrk_h / 2); // For centering the watermark on any image
   // imagecopy($img, $watermark, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $wtrmrk_w, $wtrmrk_h);
    $marge_right = $img_w - $wtrmrk_w - 5;
    $marge_bottom = 5;
    imagecopy($img, $watermark, imagesx($img) - $wtrmrk_w - $marge_right, imagesy($img) - $wtrmrk_h - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, $wtrmrk_w, $wtrmrk_h);
    imagejpeg($img, $newcopy, 100);
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($watermark);
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting the image and decrease the quality. `ImageJPEG($dst, $savePath, $quality--);`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I remove the `do {...}while` part and replace with `ImageJPEG($dst, $savePath, 100);` but still quality drop

Comment: Downscaling always decreases quality. Can you show a before/after image? Did you try another image format like PNG to make sure it is not a JPG problem?

Comment: @MarkusZeller [before](https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/GXJLadGuOsxIPh2TgvJUwyeUyLkg-FIl1NGbc6Bprt7oo3L_PQzAwZaxGcIYH2GGjjnH=w3072-h1388) and [after](https://dlandroid.com/images/MyStory.today-Write-your-own-book.jpg)

Comment: Where is the watermark code? It looks like is more going on than that small piece of code.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I remove watermark on my test but still quality drop. I add watermark code to question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're decreasing the image size and the quality drops. What exactly do you expect? Do you observe a quality drop without decreasing the size?

Comment: Still my question saving as PNG was not answered. How's the quality loss there?

Comment: You'll want to try other copy methods, like `imagecopyresampled`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I save it as PNG and still lose quality